# JSON content for POST request @OneToMany bidirectional relationship (Spring Boot)

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

While I was practicing to implement OneToMany bididrectional association I got stuck in implementing a very specific scenario in POST method. 
So, I have two entities as follows :

##### User Entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id ;

    private String username ;
    private String password ;
    private String email ;
    private String firstname ;
    private String lastname ;

    @OneToMany(
            mappedBy = "user" ,
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL ,
            orphanRemoval = true
    )
    private List<Playlist> playlists = new ArrayList<>() ;

    // getters and setters
}
```

##### Playlist Entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "playlist")
public class Playlist {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String name;
    private String description;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User user;

    // getters and setters

}
```

##### POST method in UserController Class

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/users")
public class userController {

    @Autowired
    UserService userService ;

    // ... other controller mappings

    @PostMapping("")
    public User createUser(@RequestBody User reqUser){
        return userService.createUser(reqUser) ;
    }
}
```

##### createUser method in UserService Class

```
@Service
public class UserService {

    @Autowired
    UserRepo userRepo ;

    public List<User> getAllUsers() {
        List <User> users = new ArrayList<>() ;
        userRepo.findAll().forEach(users::add);
        return users ;
    }

    public User createUser(User reqUser) {
        User newUser = new User() ;
        newUser.setUsername(reqUser.getUsername());
        newUser.setEmail(reqUser.getEmail());
        newUser.setPassword(reqUser.getPassword());
        newUser.setFirstname(reqUser.getFirstname());
        newUser.setLastname(reqUser.getLastname());

        // adding playlists 
        List<Playlist> playlists = new ArrayList<>() ;
        reqUser.getPlaylists().forEach(playlists::add);
        newUser.setPlaylists(playlists);

        userRepo.save(newUser) ;

        return newUser ;
    }
}
```

---

I want to pass a specific POST request for creating new user where we also pass down some data about playlists that doesn't exist yet into the db. To demonstrate this below is a JSON object I pass down as POST request:

```
{
    "username" : "poodie" ,
    "password" : "randomPasswrod" ,
    "firstname" : "Raj" ,
    "lastname" : "Bhushan" ,
    "playlists" : [
        {
            "name" : "playlist-01" ,
            "description" : "first playlist" 
            
        } ,

        {
            "name" : "playlist-01" ,
            "description" : "first playlist" 
        }
    ]
}
```

Sadly, this doesn't help me out to properly establish a relation between a USER record and several PLAYLIST records, which can be seen in the response JSON I receive from a POST request:

```
{
    "id": 12,
    "username": "poodie",
    "password": "randomPasswrod",
    "email": null,
    "firstname": "Raj",
    "lastname": "Bhushan",
    "playlists": [
        {
            "id": 9,
            "name": "playlist-01",
            "description": "first playlist",
            "user": null,
            "songs": []
        },
        {
            "id": 10,
            "name": "playlist-02",
            "description": "first playlist",
            "user": null,
            "songs": []
        }
    ]
}
```

**Why is the user field set to null for each playlist object, and most importantly how to fix this ??**

Comment: what happen in db? is user_id column also null?

Comment: You never set the User in the PlayList.

Comment: @Erwin yeh inside db also user_id values are null

Comment: @p3consulting that's what I am asking, I thought since I m using Cascading on `User Entity so User will be automatically set in the Playlist. Can you explain where did I go wrong ?

Comment: Cascading controls the SQL generated not the assign of Java field backing the relationship. Look at this example: https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-onetomany-association-with-jpa-and-hibernate/, the addComment() method of the Bidirectional @OneToMany.

Comment: @p3consulting thank you for the response, just to ensure I m doing it right way, this is what I did : In the createUser method I first persisted the entity for Playlists into the DB and then used a custom method to define relation between a `User` and `Playlist` records

Comment: so you use 2 times save? u can also save user first and then save playlists

Comment: @humbleCodes Please make sure you are setting the user reference in your Playlist entity as well.

Comment: private List<Playlist> playlists = new ArrayList<>() ; try editing this to "private List<Playlist> playlists". No need to create an object here. Just the reference is enough.

Comment: As p3consulting hinted, your entities are not fully built when you turn your JSON into java objects. If you inspect them, you'd likely see that User has playlists, but playlist.user is left null. This is a JSON issue, not JPA one, as your circular reference isn't represented in your JSON data. You can manually check your User instance and fix all referenced playlists before saving so that they reference the User. Or you can fix your JSON mappings - you'll need to do the later as you will get a stackoverflowException if you try to send back a User instance via JSON.

Comment: There are many many questions and answers describing how to handle bidirectional relationships in Jackson/JSON, which multiple options and solutions that might fit your use case ranging from marking one side as JSONIgnore to having Jackson manage the relationships by sending back the ID only from one side.

Comment: @Chris can you provide the link to particular resources that you are referring to by this statement of yours, `There are many many questions and answers describing how to handle bidirectional relationships in Jackson/JSON`

Comment: Search on Jackson and bidirectional relationships. You'd also get hits with stackoverflowexception, JSON etc. https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-bidirectional-relationships-and-infinite-recursion will save you some time as it outlines what is involved.